# sql oracle select different amount field

Tags: sql, oracle, field

i have one table like this:

```
| criteria | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun | jul |
|A         |100  |100  |100  |100  |100  |100  |100  |
|B         |200  |200  |200  |200  |200  |200  |200  |
```

i want select field based on month.
if the month is january, so i want my table look like this

```
| criteria | jan |
|A         |100  |
|B         |200  |
```

if the month is march, so i want my table look like this

```
| criteria | jan | feb | mar |
|A         |100  |100  |100  |
|B         |200  |200  |200  |
```

please help me, thanks...

Comment: are we talking about sql selecting? select  criteria , jan , feb , mar , apr , may , jun , jul from your_table  , then leave the unwanted columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if you don't mind your result coming back as xml.

here is some sample data

```
CREATE TABLE table1
AS
   SELECT 'A' criteria,
          100 jan,
          100 feb,
          100 mar,
          100 apr
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B',
          200,
          200,
          200,
          200
     FROM DUAL;
```

I only went up to april but you get the idea.
here is the result just brining back January.

```
WITH sql_statements
     AS (SELECT 'select criteria, jan from table1' jan,
                'select criteria, jan, feb from table1' feb,
                'select criteria, jan, feb, mar from table1' mar,
                'select criteria, jan, feb, mar, apr from table1' apr
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.getxmltype (jan)
  FROM sql_statements;
```

result

```
  <ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <CRITERIA>A</CRITERIA>
  <JAN>100</JAN>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <CRITERIA>B</CRITERIA>
  <JAN>200</JAN>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

now change your query to to april.

```
WITH sql_statements
     AS (SELECT 'select criteria, jan from table1' jan,
                'select criteria, jan, feb from table1' feb,
                'select criteria, jan, feb, mar from table1' mar,
                'select criteria, jan, feb, mar, apr from table1' apr
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.getxmltype (apr)
  FROM sql_statements;
```

result

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <CRITERIA>A</CRITERIA>
  <JAN>100</JAN>
  <FEB>100</FEB>
  <MAR>100</MAR>
  <APR>100</APR>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <CRITERIA>B</CRITERIA>
  <JAN>200</JAN>
  <FEB>200</FEB>
  <MAR>200</MAR>
  <APR>200</APR>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```